# How "many" non-reduced spaces with smooth reduction are there?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, coherent-sheaves

Suppose $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ is an analytic subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$, such that its reduction is simply some $\mathbb{C}^k\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$. How "many" such structure sheaves are there?

It is clear that there are at least countably many, by considering the ideals generated by monomials $z_{k+1}^{p_1},...,z_{n}^{p_{n-k}},(z_{k+1}\cdot z_{k_2})^{p_{12}},...,(z_{k+1}\cdot {\dots} \cdot z_n)^{p_{1...n-k}}$, with $p_1\neq 0,...,p_{n-k}\neq 0$. Let me call these ideals $I_{p_1,...,p_{1\dots n-k}}$. Moreover, for any defining ideal $J$ of such an $M$ it follows that there exist numbers $q_1,...,q_{1\dots n-k}$ such that

$I_{q_1,...,q_{1\dots n-k}}\subseteq J$.

This is a consequence of the Nullstellensatz. It follows that elements of $J/I_{q_1,...,q_{1\dots n-k}}$ are only polynomials in $z_{k+1},...,z_n$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^k}$. Showing that the ideal $J$ is generated by polynomials $P_i$ in $z_{k+1},...,z_n$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^k}$.

May one further deduce that $J$ is generated by monomials in $z_{k+1},...,z_n$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^k}$? How "bad" can the ideal $J$ still be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many more than what you've listed. Specifically, for any closed analytic subspace $X\subset M$, we can find a complex analytic structure on $M$ which is non-reduced along $X$ by taking the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb C^n}/(\mathcal{I}_M\cdot\mathcal{I}_X)$. This will give you at least uncountably many. On the other hand, I think the amount of non-reduced structures is at most uncountable: every complex-analytic space is locally isomorphic to a model space of the form $V(I)\subset U\subset \Bbb C^n$ where $I$ is a finitely-generated ideal of the ring of holomorphic functions on the open subset $U$, so since $\Bbb C^n$ is second-countable, we can specify $M$ by choosing finitely many things from an uncountable set countably many times. (Apologies to anyone who's a serious set-theorist if I've butchered anything in the previous sentence.)

Here is an explicit example: let $n=2$, $m=1$, and take some finite list of values $z_1,\cdots,z_l\in\Bbb C$. Then the ideal $$(\prod (x_1-z_i),x_2))\cdot(x_2)=(x_2\prod(x_1-z_i),x_2^2)$$ gives a copy of $\Bbb C$ with nilpotence at each of the $z_i$. This also shows that your "may one further..." question is false.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but your example is an ideal generated by monomials with coefficients that are analytic functions in $x_1$, i.e. $(x_1-z_1)\cdot{\dots}\cdot (x_1-z_l)$. Your first remark definitely clears up the question of how many there are.

Comment: @t312t I don't think we're on the same page - I would not consider $(x_1(x_1-1)x_2,x_2^2)$ generated by monomials in the $x_i$ with coefficients from $\mathcal{O}$. Expanding, $x_1(x_1-1)x_2=x_1^2x_2-x_1x_2$, and that's a polynomial which is not a monomial. (Hang on, perhaps the issue is that I'm using $x_i$ for coordinates and you're using $z_i$?)

Comment: Well, wouldn't you agree that in the ring $\mathcal{O}[x_2]$ an element of the form $f(x_1)\cdot x_2$ is a monomial in that polynomial ring? Anyway, with monomial with coefficients from $\mathcal{O}$ I mean precisely such things.

Comment: @t312t I guess - maybe I didn't read your conditions correctly the first time around. I still think this is not true in general - try something like $(px_2+qx_2^2,x_2^3)$, for instance.

Comment: You are correct. The ideal $I=(x_1\cdot x_2 +x_2^2,x_2^3)$ is not generated by monomials. If it were then $x_1\cdot x_2\in I$ which is not the case. The reduction of the analytic space defined by $I$ is simply the $0$-dimensional manifold $(0,\mathbb{C})$.